# Can you remove Android signing v1 from an existing app's APK?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

Our existing app which is in production and available in the Play store is signed using both V1 and V2 of the signature scheme. Our security team has advised us to remove the v1 option as we no longer want to support Android OS < 7 and to avoid the security issues of v1 such as the Janus vulnerability.

The question is, can you do remove the V1 signing and leave the V2 signing untouched without needing to publish a brand new version of the app to the store and require your users to switch?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot remove v1 signing without updating the app, you can remove v1 signing from build.gradle using the option enableV1Signing false.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing me to that option! Sorry, I wasn't very clear in the second part of my question. Would we need to publish a brand new app in the Play store for this change or would it simply be normal version update for users?

Comment: version update is enough. no need of new app

Comment: min version at least of 24 to be able to disable v1 scheme

Comment: @RADU Can you please share the Android document link for your statement ?

Comment: I do not remember but in this document https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner states this:  --v1-signing-enabled <true | false>
Determines whether apksigner signs the given APK package using the traditional, JAR-based signing scheme. By default, the tool uses the values of --min-sdk-version and --max-sdk-version to decide when to apply this signature scheme.   So adjusting the min-sdk-version I was able to remove v1 scheme.

Answer (score 3):

If your Android project supports minSDK version 23 or lower then V1 singing is enabled. To remove V1 singing please use below code in your APP level gradle.

signingConfigs {
create("signingConfigRelease") {
---------------------------
enableV1Signing = false
}
}

But if you publish the app in playStore then it will always show V1 singing. To avoid this please change minSDK version to 24.